# Finding duplicates in one column that have a different code/ID in another column

Tags: duplicates, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been fighting this one for awhile

I have a table full of duplicate locations that I made using the following query;

```
select * from Table A where location in
(select location from Table A
group by location having count(*) >1);
```

The duplicate locations should have the same code associated with them. If there is a duplicated location that has a different code compared to the others then I want to select which ones they are

I have this example table

```
Table A
code    location
111     x12345
111     x12345
222     y12346
222     y12346
111     y12346
222     z12348
333     z12348
333     r12340
333     r12340
```

I want to select all of the duplicated locations that have a different code. So for example the output should look like this

```
code    location
222     y12346
222     y12346
111     y12346
222     z12348
333     z12348
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [an analytic `count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html) to get the number of code used for each location:

```
select code, location,
  count(distinct code) over (partition by location) as cnt
from TableA
```

and then use that as a subquery, filtering on that count being > 1:

```
select code, location
from (
  select code, location,
    count(distinct code) over (partition by location) as cnt
  from TableA
)
where cnt > 1;

      CODE LOCATION
---------- --------
       111 y12346  
       222 y12346  
       222 y12346  
       222 z12348  
       333 z12348
```

Comment: This gets me almost there! Is it possible with this to return all columns from my original table? I know in my example I only have 2 but in the table I'm working with I have many. I suppose a workaround would be to create a new table with this and join to the original to identify those locations.

Comment: Just include all the columns you want to see in both the select lists.

Comment: Oh maybe my formatting was weird working now. THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

Yet another (though not better) option, without analytics:

```
SQL> with tableA (code, location) as
  2  (select 111, 'x12345' from dual union
  3   select 111, 'x12345' from dual union
  4   select 222, 'y12346' from dual union
  5   select 222, 'y12346' from dual union
  6   select 111, 'y12346' from dual union
  7   select 222, 'z12348' from dual union
  8   select 333, 'z12348' from dual union
  9   select 333, 'r12340' from dual union
 10   select 333, 'r12340' from dual
 11  )
 12  select code, location
 13  from tableA
 14  where location in (select location from tableA
 15                     group by location
 16                     having count(distinct code) > 1);

      CODE LOCATI
---------- ------
       333 z12348
       222 z12348
       222 y12346
       111 y12346

SQL>
```